# Slow query when using status column as condition (status column has index)

Tags: mysql

I'm working with mysql, and I'm working with a 6.9GB table, about 28 million records.....

This table has several columns, some of which are index/foreign keys to other tables....

I noticed that when I do a query with a specific condition (status_pedido_id = 2), the query is much slower...

Without this status_pedido_id condition, it responds in less than 1 second
With this status 2, it goes up to more than 20 seconds....

If the search is done without status condition, the search is very fast.

If I add the status, it starts to take a while...

Why?

a funny thing is that, if I use an establishment with more sales, this query is faster, if I use a customer with less sales, the query takes much longer.

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `pedidos` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_pedido_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 - Venda, 2 - Comissão, 3 - Assinatura',
  `usuario_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `cliente_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `estabelecimento_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketplace_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_pedido_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `cliente_cartao_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_bruto` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `valor_liquido` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `tipo_pagamento` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bandeira` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parcelas` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `markup` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `capture_mode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zoop_transaction_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zoop_plan_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pos_identification_number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorization_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorization_nsu` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oculto` int DEFAULT '0',
  `splitted_taxa_recorrente` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `splitted_link` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `splitted_sale` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `splitted_invoice` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `splitted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `taxed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `antecipado` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referencia` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `msg_erro` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `online_taxed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `removed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cliente_id` (`cliente_id`),
  KEY `usuario_id` (`usuario_id`),
  KEY `estabelecimento_id` (`estabelecimento_id`),
  KEY `status_pedido_id` (`status_pedido_id`),
  KEY `zoop_transaction_id` (`zoop_transaction_id`),
  KEY `pos_identification_id` (`pos_identification_number`),
  KEY `bandeira` (`bandeira`),
  KEY `removed` (`removed`),
  KEY `listagemVendas` (`parent_id`,`created`,`oculto`,`marketplace_id`),
  KEY `pedidos_cliente_cartao_id_foreign_idx` (`cliente_cartao_id`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `idx_marketplace_id` (`marketplace_id`),
  KEY `processed` (`processed`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_cliente_cartao_id_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_cartao_id`) REFERENCES `clientes_cartoes` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_id`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_id`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`estabelecimento_id`) REFERENCES `estabelecimentos` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`status_pedido_id`) REFERENCES `status_pedidos` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50717358 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Fast query:

SELECT * FROM pedidos where marketplace_id = 64 limit 100;

Response time: 20ms

SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE marketplace_id = 64 and status_pedido_id = 1 limit 100;

Response time: 900ms (4 results)

Slow query:
SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE marketplace_id = 64 and status_pedido_id = 2 limit 100;

Response time: 30+ seconds

Obs: status 2 has much more than a hundred results

Other query:
SELECT * FROM pedidos where  marketplace_id = 64 and status_pedido_id = 3 limit 100;

Response time: 600ms - 100 results

###### Update explain analyze

Fast query

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM pedidos where  marketplace_id = 64 and status_pedido_id = 3 limit 100;

-> Limit: 100 row(s)  (cost=7596.98 rows=100) (actual time=894.745..960.513 rows=100 loops=1)
    -> Filter: ((pedidos.status_pedido_id = 3) and (pedidos.marketplace_id = 64))  (cost=7596.98 rows=8882) (actual time=894.744..960.501 rows=100 loops=1)
        -> Intersect rows sorted by row ID  (cost=7596.98 rows=8883) (actual time=894.738..960.426 rows=100 loops=1)
            -> Index range scan on pedidos using idx_marketplace_id over (marketplace_id = 64)  (cost=102.01 rows=108180) (actual time=0.086..0.890 rows=1938 loops=1)
            -> Index range scan on pedidos using status_pedido_id over (status_pedido_id = 3)  (cost=674.22 rows=2326222) (actual time=0.041..888.081 rows=882406 loops=1)
```

Slow Query:

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM pedidos where  marketplace_id = 64 and status_pedido_id = 2 limit 100;

-> Limit: 100 row(s)  (cost=36770.23 rows=100) (actual time=224685.952..225138.592 rows=100 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (pedidos.marketplace_id = 64)  (cost=36770.23 rows=54062) (actual time=224685.951..225138.572 rows=100 loops=1)
        -> Index range scan on pedidos using status_pedido_id over (status_pedido_id = 2), with index condition: (pedidos.status_pedido_id = 2)  (cost=36770.23 rows=14164526) (actual time=0.069..223866.996 rows=15977367 loops=1)
```

Comment: You should have a SINGLE index to better match your query.  Try one on KEY 'market_status' ( marketplace_id, status_pedido_id )

Comment: so should i create a key containing the two columns?

Comment: Maybe post the EXPLAIN output for both the fast query and the slow query.  That might help to identify what choices the query engine is making in selecting indices

Comment: Updated with explain analyze...
It helps?

Comment: @Dayglor, correct. a SINGLE INDEX that has both components to the where clause vs two individual.  The engine can only pick ONE index.  So the better index is the one that has the most columns available matching the WHERE clause being applied.